# NullPointerException when adding an Item to the list

Tags: android

Helo All,

I have a problem that I am facing NullPointerException when I want to add an item to the List, as shown below:

```
public List<SearchResponse> sortMPGListViewForNA(List<SearchResponse> response)
    {
        List<SearchResponse> list = response;
        List<SearchResponse> tempMPG = null, tempPrice = null, tempRating = null;
        for(int i=0;i<response.size();i++)
        {
            if(response.get(i).years.get(0).mpg.equalsIgnoreCase("n/a"))
            {
                tempMPG.add(response.get(i));
                list.remove(i);
            }
            if(response.get(i).years.get(0).price.equalsIgnoreCase("n/a"))
            {
                tempPrice.add(response.get(i));
                list.remove(i);
            }
            if(response.get(i).years.get(0).rating.equalsIgnoreCase("n/a"))
            {
                tempRating.add(response.get(i));//NPE Occurs Here
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
        response.addAll(tempMPG);
        response.addAll(tempPrice);
        response.addAll(tempRating);
        return response;
    }
```

Please suggest me any solution regarding to the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize tempMPG, tempPrice and tempRating:

```
tempMpg = new ArrayList<SearchResponse>();
tempPrice = new ArrayList<SearchResponse>();
tempRating = new ArrayList<SearchResponse>();
```